# prove this ODE solution is genuine?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Prove that the solution to:
$y'-2y\tan x=2x\sec x$ is $$y=\frac{2\left(x\sin\left(x\right)+\cos \left(x\right)\right)+C}{\cos^2\left(x\right)}$$

I have found the derivative: $$\frac{2x\cos^3\left(x\right)+\sin \left(2x\right)\left(2\left(x\sin \left(x\right)+\cos \left(x\right)\right)+C\right)}{\cos ^4\left(x\right)}$$

But cannot substitute derivative into original equation to prove

Comment: Why can't you? What you have is $y'$, and you have $y$. Substitute them into the left-hand side and simplify.

Comment: I'm getting lost in the simplification and can't seem to equate terms

Answer (score 0):

Treating it as a linear first order ODE, then proceed to find the integrating factor: $$\mu = e^{\int -2\tan xdx}= e^{2\ln (\cos x)}= \cos^2 x $$

$$\implies (y\cos^2x)' = 2x\sec x\cdot \cos^2x=2x\cos x$$

$$\implies y\cos^2x= \displaystyle \int 2x\cos xdx$$

$$ =  \int 2xd(\sin x)$$
$$= 2x\sin x- \int 2\sin xdx$$
$$= 2x\sin x+2\cos x+C$$
$$\implies y = \dfrac{2x\sin x+2\cos x +C}{\cos^2x}$$ as claimed above.

Comment: thanks, but I'm trying to substitute the solution back into the original equation to prove its correct.

Comment: @filipe: I understand your point, but it seems that they want you to solve it and arrive at the solution above instead of plugging them into the equation and check for both sides to equal.